# google charts - custom formatter to show time duration

Tags: google-visualization

I want to show the time duration(in seconds) in a string format as (HH:MM:SS) on google chart's y-axis instead of seconds(i.e. in number).
I had searched about it a lot but didn't find a proper solution at anywhere.